# Хочу написать кнопку на картинке чтобы перенаправлять на сайт

Tags: javascript

Я использую:

```html
<button onclick="GG"> </button>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
    
    function GG() {window.location = 'Dino.html';}
</script>
```

Comment: Обычно принято создавать ссылку и в нее уже класть картинку

Answer (score 2):

В JS есть такая штука как `window.location.href`. Он указывает на адрес страницы. Если написать в тело функции "GG" строчку `window.location.href`, то он выполнит то, что вам нужно.

```html
<button onclick="GG()">Кнопка</button>
<script>
  function GG() {
    window.location.href = 'Dino.html'
  }
</script>
```

А насчёт кнопки на картинке, вот сайт, читайте [здесь](https://coderlipi.com/images/js-red.png)

Comment: Просто не подходит. Оно пишется над картинкой

Comment: @Kekkx, готово, дополнил ответ.

Comment: ммм это просто картинка. Пустая картинка с надписью JS